# Join query using three tables and display missing records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables in a database that I am querying:

players

| Player_id | Player_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom |
| 2 | Dick |
| 3 | Harry |

games

| Game_id | Game_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Tennis |
| 2 | Rugby |
| 3 | Cricket |

Games_Players

| game_id | player_id | Date_Played |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-12-20 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-12-20 |
| 2 | 3 | 2021-12-21 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-12-22 |
| 3 | 3 | 2021-12-22 |

I want a query that will return the players id, name, game name and Date Played. If they have not played a game - as in the case of Tom (1) and Dick (2) - then I want the id, player name, game name and a null value.

Desired Result

| player_id | player_name | game_name | Date_Played |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tom | Tennis | null |
| 1 | Tom | Rugby | null |
| 1 | Tom | Cricket | null |
| 2 | Dick | Tennis | 2021-12-20 |
| 2 | Dick | Rugby | null |
| 2 | Dick | Cricket | 2021-12-22 |
| 3 | Harry | Tennis | 2021-12-20 |
| 3 | Harry | Rugby | 2021-12-21 |
| 3 | Harry | Cricket | 2021-12-22 |

I've tried the below query, which is closest I can get, and I've tried other joins, but I can't seem to get all the data I need:

```
SELECT players.player_id, players.player_name, games.game_name, Games_Players.Date_Played,
FROM players
LEFT OUTER JOIN Games_Players
LEFT OUTER JOIN games
ON players.player_id = Games_Players.player_id
AND Games_Players.game_id=games.game_id
```

It's not returning all the records I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cross join` to join the `players` table to the `games` table and then join the result to the `Games_Players` table

```
select 
    t1.player_id,
    t1.player_name,
    t1.game_name,
    t2.Date_Played

from
  (select * 
   from players p
   cross join games g) t1
left join Games_Players t2
on t1.Player_id = t2.Player_id and t1.game_id = t2.game_id
```

demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df829ed8352f41b274352530a14ead57)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not add the columns for the first join with table `Game_Players`.
Also, you have a comma after the last column in select section. So, your query should be:

```sql
SELECT players.player_id, 
players.player_name, 
games.game_name, 
Games_Players.Date_Played
FROM players
LEFT OUTER JOIN Games_Players 
ON players.id = Games_Players.player_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN games
ON players.player_id = Games_Players.player_id
AND Games_Players.game_id=games.game_id
```